# changing file names according to parent directory name

Tags: bash

Hello I have several directories of this tendency:

```
cluster1_bin.101_res/

cluster1_bin.102_res/

cluster1_bin.103_res/

cluster1_bin.104_res/
```

in each of these direcories I have several files with `".gbk"` suffix like the following ones:

```
cluster1_bin.101_res/k141_734976.region001.gbk

cluster1_bin.101_res/k141_753945.region001.gbk

cluster1_bin.101_res/k141_743978.region001.gbk
```

**and I need to replace everything that is before .region001.gbk for it's parent directory name**

this is the desired output:

```
cluster1_bin.101_res/cluster1_bin.101_res.region001.gbk

cluster1_bin.101_res/cluster1_bin.101_res.region001.gbk

cluster1_bin.101_res/cluster1_bin.101_res.region001.gbk
```

Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `for` loop and [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and `mv` to rename the files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in cluster1_bin.[0-9]*_res/*.gbk; do
  path_name=${file%/*}
  file_name=${file##*/}
  region_with_extension=${file_name#*.}
  echo mv -v "$file" "$path_name/$path_name.$region_with_extension" || exit
done
```

---

With your given input/data the output is:

```
mv -v cluster1_bin.101_res/k141_734976.region001.gbk cluster1_bin.101_res/cluster1_bin.101_res.region001.gbk
mv -v cluster1_bin.102_res/k141_753945.region001.gbk cluster1_bin.102_res/cluster1_bin.102_res.region001.gbk
mv -v cluster1_bin.103_res/k141_743978.region001.gbk cluster1_bin.103_res/cluster1_bin.103_res.region001.gbk
```

---

- Remove the `echo` If you think the output is correct so `mv` can rename the files.

Comment: You do know that SO is supposed to NOT be a coding service, don't you?

Comment: A lot of posted answers now, where are you?